# NSDateComponents in Swift is not returning Weekday

Tags: ios, swift, nsdate, nsdatecomponents

```
import UIKit

let components = NSDateComponents()
components.setValue(1, forComponent: NSCalendarUnit.CalendarUnitDay)
components.setValue(1, forComponent: NSCalendarUnit.CalendarUnitMonth)
components.setValue(2014, forComponent: NSCalendarUnit.CalendarUnitYear)

println(components.weekday) // 9223372036854775807
```

Anyone have any ideas as to why I'm getting `9223372036854775807` instead of a value from 1-7?

Comment: Do you need to know the weekday from a date?

Comment: You never extracted weekday.

Comment: From the [spec](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateComponents_Class/):  An instance of NSDateComponents is not responsible for answering questions about a date beyond the information with which it was initialized. For example, if you initialize one with May 6, 2004, its weekday is NSUndefinedDateComponent, not Thursday.

Comment: he can easily extract the week day as you can see on my answer

Comment: Then how can I get a weekday of any random date?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
let dateStyler = NSDateFormatter()
dateStyler.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"

let myDate = dateStyler.dateFromString("2014-01-01")!

let myWeekday = NSCalendar.currentCalendar().components(NSCalendarUnit.CalendarUnitWeekday, fromDate: myDate).weekday
```